# How to hide error & warning bash colors in Xcode and Source Tree?

Tags: xcode, bash, atlassian-sourcetree

I have following bash script

```
    while read -r line; do

    FILEPATH=$(echo $line | cut -d : -f 1)
    L=$(echo $line | cut -d : -f 2)
    C=$(echo $line | cut -d : -f 3)
    TYPE=$(echo $line | cut -d : -f 4 | cut -c 2-)
    MESSAGE=$(echo $line | cut -d : -f 5 | cut -c 2-)
    DESCRIPTION=$(echo $line | cut -d : -f 6 | cut -c 2-)
    if [ "$TYPE" == 'error' ]; then
        printf "\n  \e[31m$TYPE\e[39m\n"
    else
        printf "\n  \e[33m$TYPE\e[39m\n"
    fi
    printf "    \e[90m$FILEPATH:$L:$C\e[39m\n"
    printf "    $MESSAGE - $DESCRIPTION\n"
done <<< "$RESULT"
```

In terminal colors works perfectly.
How to hide colors in Xcode & Source Tree?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the colour escape sequences are hard-coded into the script, they will always come out of it. Quite trivial. You need to implement logic to return different strings (i.e. w/o colours) depending on some condition.

Comment: How to recognize application type? Xcode or Source Tree, Terminal?

Comment: Pass in a command line argument to the invocation, e.g. `/bin/bash path/to/script.sh use-colours` then make the script generate different output based on the presence or lack of that argument and call it with from terminal and w/o from elsewhere.

Comment: Or just completely remove colours and free yourself from the hassle?